# Changing the value of an array through a foreach statement VB.net

Tags: vb.net, arrays, csv

I am making a program that automates the seperation of a csv file.  We read the csv in through and then assign the "line" using a split command to an array.  After that we go through each "cell" in the array and put an = in front because this causes leading zeros not to be lost.  Here's the code.

```
        arLine = line.Split(replace)

        For Each cell As String In arLine
            cell = cell.Replace(",", "")
            cell = String.Format(cellFormat, cell)
        Next
```

arLine is the array and replace is the delimiter, in this case a pipe not that it matters.'

When it goes through, the arLine is correct but the values in each cell are not changing, any thoughts? newer to VB.net and need direction

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with this.

```
arLine = line.Split(replace)          
For x as Integer = 0 To arLine.Length - 1             
    arLine(x) = arLine(x).Replace(",", "")             
    arLine(x) = String.Format(cellFormat, arLine(x))         
Next
```

You are looping using For Each and trying to modify the value returned by the iterator, but this creates a new string for your cell var, so you are not referencing the original array.
Using a traditional For loop instead lets you directly update the values in the arLine array.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm, still confused why the foreach didn't work, but i spose it doesn't matter

Answer (score 5):

Strings in .NET are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).  When you modify a string, you actually create a brand-new string.

So, cell no longer refers to the original array element.  Instead, try a `for` loop rather than a `foreach` loop and assign the modified value back to `arLine(i)`.

Use a `for` loop rather than `foreach` so that you have a handy index into the collection.